# Using startswith() but doesn't contain the specified element

Tags: python

I currently want my program to deal with string depending on what they contain:

```
if x.startswith("_") and "_" in x:
            split_items = x.split("_")
            convert_to_uppercase = [a.upper() for a in split_items]
            split_items = [change.capitalize() for change in split_items]
            final_items.append('_'.join(split_items))
            
        
        elif not x.startswith("_") and not "_" in x:
            final_items.append(x)
            
        elif x.startswith("_") and not "_" in x:
            final_items.append(x)
```

So for example I want `_hellothere`,  `_hello_there` and `hellothere` to be processed differently, is that possible using the existing if statements?

Comment: If `x.startswith("_")` is true, then `"_" in x` is trivially true as well.

Comment: You probably want to split `x` first, then look at how many elements are in the resulting list. If `x` starts with `_`, then the `x.split("_")[0] == ""`.

Comment: You can use str.split() and put conditions on length of resulting list. Please also  see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `x[1:]` to check remaining elements in that string

```py
list1 = ['_hellothere', '_hello_there', 'hellothere']
final_items = []
for x in list1:
  if x.startswith("_") and "_" in x[1:]:
      split_items = x.split("_")
      convert_to_uppercase = [a.upper() for a in split_items]
      split_items = [change.capitalize() for change in split_items]
      final_items.append('_'.join(split_items))
      
  elif not x.startswith("_") and not "_" in x[1:]:
      final_items.append(x)
      
  elif x.startswith("_") and not "_" in x[1:]:
      final_items.append(x)

print(final_items)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to have `_hellothere`, `_hello_there` and `hellothere` be processed differenty this should work.

```
if x.startswith("_") and "_" not in x[1:]:
    #Proccess for _hellothere

elif not x.startswith("_") and not "_" in x:
    #Process for hellothere

elif x.startswith("_") and "_" in x[1:]:
    #Process for _hello_there
```

I hope this may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @chepner said, if x starts with ' _ ' then ' _ ' obviously exists in x. So if you remove the ' _ ' exists in x it would be better.

Secondly,

'_hellothere' should pass through the first if statement.

'hellothere' should pass through the first elif statement.

However, for '_hello_there' it should pass through the first if statement again. If you want a different output for it then try:

```
elif x.startswith("_") and x.count("_") > 1:
    # Do something
```

Here it checks if it starts with ' _ ' and then counts the number of ' _ ' in x and if its greater than 1, it executes.

If this answer helped, kindly upvote and mark as correct. Appreciate it!